# Как ответить на свой вопрос?

Tags: поддержка

Задал вопрос, в последствии нашёл ответ, как ответить на свой вопрос?

Comment: А вообще -- просто добавить свой ответ. Что мешает?

Comment: @MaximKorshunov , спасибо , а ведь негде ,здесь большая кнопка внизу ответа, ответить на свой вопрос , а там ничего такого нету

Comment: Не понял вас... Там - это где? Я просто один раз отвечал на свой же вопрос, просто добавил свой ответ, так же как и на чужие вопросы добавляю ответы. Вот пример: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689037/preg-replace-for-a-template-which-excludes-the-specified-set-of-words

Answer (score 4):

Ответом на ваш вопрос является публикация в справочном центре «[Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)».

---

Да, ответить можно и, более того, даже нужно!

> Чтобы опубликовать вопрос одновременно с собственным ответом:
>
> - нажмите на «Задать вопрос»;
> - заполните необходимые поля;
> - под полем для ввода текста вопроса отметьте галкой пункт «Ответить на собственный вопрос»;
> - в появившееся поле ввода добавьте текст ответа;
> - опубликуйте вопрос вместе с ответом.
>
> Вы также можете в любой момент вернуться в вопрос и опубликовать
>   решение:
>
> - если вы нашли решение быстрее, чем сообщество;
> - если вы нашли лучшее решение, чем уже предложенные;
> - если ответы только подтолкнули вас к идеи реализации, а полное решение вы нашли сами.

Для того, чтобы ответить на свой вопрос, после того как вы нашли решение:

- перейдите на страницу вашего вопроса;
- прокрутите страницу вниз;
- нажмите на кнопку «Ответить на собственный вопрос» и подтвердите ваше намерение;
- введите ваш ответ в появившееся поле ввода и нажмите «Отправить ваш ответ».

Comment: я смотрел эту страницу  прежде чем спросить , на этот вопрос выдаётся такая кнопка , но на тот вопрос который я хочу ответить (мой предыдущий вопрос) такой кнопки на странице не имеется ,  может быть дело в том что я  до этого нажимал на "птичку" (когда дали ответ) а потом второй раз нажал на эту самую кнопку (когда стало ясно что ответ не правилен ). Не знаю , по крайней мере  возможности ответить на свой предыдущий  вопрос  у меня нету . Вот здесь есть.

Answer (score 4):

Процедура оставления ответов на собственные вопросы нисколько не отличается от обычной.

---

Как выяснилось, речь шла о вопросе ["Javascript, игра крестики-нолики"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558444/javascript-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/558678?noredirect=1).

Он получил 5 голосов за закрытие и **возможность оставлять к нему ответы закрыта** (о чём свидетельствует плашка со словами **требует правки**).

Закрыта не только для вас. **Для всех.**